# Selenium C# cannot find Element using Id, Name or XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find an element on a page that is inside a panel(or table, I'm not sure). When using the ID or Name it cannot be located. I am now trying to find the element using the XPath but having trouble. Firebug is no longer supported and I can't locate it using Firefox Development tools (copy XPath) either. I have tried adding wait exceptions and switch frames. I have tried the following code:

```
web.FindElement(By.XPath("//td(@contains='FirstName'))")).SendKeys("Sarah");
```

This results in

> "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : Given xpath
>   expression "//td(@contains='FirstName'))" is invalid: SyntaxError: The
>   expression is not a legal expression."

When I use Inspect Element on the webpage the output is this:

```
<tr>
  <td>First Name:</td>
  <td>
   <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxRoundPane14_txtFirstName" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ASPxRoundPanel4$txtFirstName" type="text">
   <br>
   <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxRoundPanel4_RequiredFieldValidator2" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">First Name must be entered</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I've searched solutions for days but am still coming up empty.

Comment: if you remove .SendKeys() from the end do you still get an error ?

Comment: Have you tried using `web.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxRoundPane14_txtFirstName")`? It seems like that is a text input box for the first name value.

Comment: Ummm, cause it's not a legal expression, this is why you are getting that exception.

Comment: What element are you trying to get?  Your expression is wrong, the text you are trying to grab it by seems wrong too.  The only place I see "FirstName" is in the ID of the input.  Is this the element you are trying to get?  The input element?

Comment: I answered it below, please check if it works for you.  It has been tested to work on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the "text" of a `<td>` element since it's a block level element.

You need to set the text of the input.

You can find the input using this selector:

```
web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td > input[id$='txtFirstName']")).SendKeys("The First Name")
```

This CSS Selector means (in English):

> Find me a `<td>`, and immediately proceeding that element, find me an input, that has an `id` that `ends with` "txtFirstName"

You can see that there's not much to go on, but `txtFirstName` in the `id` attribute looks unique enough.

If you want it simpler ( remember, K.I.S.S ;) )

just use

```
web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id$='txtFirstName']")).SendKeys("The First Name")
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! This worked. I can quit beating my head against the wall. XPath and CssSelector were new to me. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: glad to hear it worked, and that you can save yourself from a headache!  go ahead and mark this question as the answer by clicking the "checkmark" below the up and down voting icons.

Comment: Mine was also right and I explained why your's didn't work as well.

Comment: I accepted the above answer because I could copy and paste. I'm new and needed something that easy. I couldn't do that with your answer. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, your expression is wrong.  You can't @ a contains.  @ is for attributes in the element.  So you want to just grab a specific part of the ID it seems "FirstName".  You will need to use "contains()" and inside the parenthesis is where you put the attribute you want to grab.  Now the way you are going about it you are saying "equals" and you aren't specifying an attribute.  So if you used an attribute, "equals" wouldn't of worked either as "equals" wants the "whole" attribute to equal only "FirstName", which is not the case in your "ID" attribute as it has more than just "FirstName".  In order to search an attribute, you need to do the following.

```
//input[contains(@id, 'FirstName')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
`web.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id,'FirstName')]")).SendKeys("Sarah");`
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to leave more information in your answer.

Comment: This still returned    "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: //td[contains(text(),'FirstName')]"